# How to encrypt and decrypt an object in java?

Tags: java, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt an object in java such that I can know who encrypted it.
Something like a digital signature on an object.

Example -

```
class Animal{
    public String name;

    public Animal(String name){
         this.name = name;
    }
}

class Client {
    public int id;
    // some more fields
    public void encrypt(Animal a){
        // some implementation
    }

    public Client(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Animal lion = new Animal("Lion");
       Client client1 = new Client(1);
       Client client2 = new Client(2);
       SomeClass c1 = client1.encrypt(lion);
       SomeClass c2 = client2.encrypt(lion);
       // let's say I have the keys corresponding to client1 and client2
       // now I want to get back the lion object from c1 and c2.
   }
}
```

I want something like a key pair, public and private keys. Read online about using the public key for encryption and the private key for decryption.

I used the wrong approach of using the public key for encryption and exposing only the private key for decryption which I read online is not recommended.

I want the client class to encrypt the object and then expose some keys that can decrypt the object this client encrypted.

Comment: I would split this into two different parts: 1) serialization/deserialization, i.e. representing your object as a sequence of bytes. 2) encryption/decryption of bytes. Both of these are pretty well-documented areas, so I suggest you research each of them separately, then edit your question to make it more specific and include the results of your research.

Comment: Yeah, I have gone through this approach, I generated public and private key pair, then encrypted using the public key and decrypted using private key... but I want to encrypt the object and decrypt it in some other thread let's say. So now I need the private key to decrypt. I do not want to expose private key as it is not recommended.

Comment: So make the private key available to the other thread... it's very unclear what challenge you're facing, and it's very unclear in your question. In particular, if you've already got the serialization part then you should narrow your question down to "encrypting some data" rather than "encrypting an object". (The fact that the data is a serialized object is irrelevant.) Fundamentally, you need to be much clearer about your requirements. If you want only your code to be able to encrypt, but anyone to decrypt, then just encrypt with the private key instead of the public one...

Comment: *...Something like a digital signature on an object...* It sounds like a digital signature. With signatures we don't say *encrypt* and *decrypt*, we instead say *sign* and *verify*. We reserve the word *encrypt* for a transformation that makes the data readable only by the intended recipient. When we *sign* something, the result is *verifiable*  (and readable) by everyone. It's possible to both sign *and* encrypt something so that only the intended recipient can read it and can know who signed it. This is described in more detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

Comment: Thanks, Jon Skeet and James K., I got the solution for my problem.